# Add captions to image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'd like to add captions to the bottom left corner of this slider but I'm not really sure how to do it.

Ideally, text should NOT slide like the images. It should behave [like this](http://rex-ny.com/). I've tried using that plugin but honestly it seems overcomplicated and this script is working just fine, it's just missing the captions...

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fswe4azh/)

HTML

```
<div id="panel8" class="panels" style=" z-index: 62">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="pictures"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hZfcYNw.jpg"></div>
        <div class="pictures"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PFkzdOd.jpg"></div>
        <div class="pictures"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yyjdlgQ.jpg"></div>
    </div>
<div class="nav">
    <div id="previous" style=" cursor: pointer">PREV</div>
    <span>|</span>
    <div id="next" style=" cursor: pointer">NEXT&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pictures').first().addClass('current').css({left: 0});

    $('#next').click(function(){
        var old = $('.current').removeClass('current');  
        if ( old.is(':last-child')) {
            old.animate({left: "-100%"});
            $('.pictures').first().css({left: "100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
        }else{
           old.animate({left: "-100%"});
           old.next().css({left: "100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
        }        
    });

    $('#previous').click(function(){
        var old = $('.current').removeClass('current');   
        if ( old.is(':first-child')) {
            old.animate({left: "100%"});
            $('.pictures').last().css({left: "-100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
        }else{
            old.animate({left: "100%"});
            old.prev().css({left: "-100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fswe4azh/2/

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pictures').first().addClass('current').css({left: 0});
    $('.panels > .caption').html($('.pictures').first().find("img")[0].src);

    $('#next').click(function(){
        var old = $('.current').removeClass('current');  
        if ( old.is(':last-child')) {
            old.animate({left: "-100%"});
            $('.pictures').first().css({left: "100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
            $('.panels > .caption').html($('.pictures').first().find("img")[0].src);
        }else{
           old.animate({left: "-100%"});
           old.next().css({left: "100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
           $('.panels > .caption').html(old.next().find("img")[0].src);
        } 
    });

    $('#previous').click(function(){
  var old = $('.current').removeClass('current');   
        if ( old.is(':first-child')) {
   old.animate({left: "100%"});
   $('.pictures').last().css({left: "-100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
            $('.panels > .caption').html($('.pictures').last().find("img")[0].src);
        }else{
   old.animate({left: "100%"});
   old.prev().css({left: "-100%"}).addClass('current').animate({left: 0});
            $('.panels > .caption').html(old.prev().find("img")[0].src);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.panels {
 position: absolute;
}

#panel8 {
 width: 360px;
 height: 180px;
}

.panels > .caption{
    margin-top: -28px; 
    position: absolute;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.pictures {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 color: #000;
 font-family: Monospace;
 font-size: 9px;
 text-align: right;
 line-height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}

#previous {
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: normal;
}

#next {
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: normal;
}

span {
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel8" class="panels" style=" z-index: 62">
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="pictures"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hZfcYNw.jpg"></div>
  <div class="pictures"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PFkzdOd.jpg"></div>
  <div class="pictures"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yyjdlgQ.jpg"></div>
 </div>
            <div class="caption">Caption</div>
<div class="nav">
 <div id="previous" style=" cursor: pointer">PREV</div>
 <span>|</span>
 <div id="next" style=" cursor: pointer">NEXT&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've added a caption to the slider and set it to `position: absolute` and a `margin` of `-20px`.

Comment: Yes, looks perfect, but where's the actual text (the address in your example) coming from? How do I edit it?

Comment: The address is coming from the image element, you can easily edit this by changing the content of `html(...)` in these lines: `$('.panels > .caption').html(old.next().find("img")[0].src);`

Comment: Okay, but how do I do that for multiple images? Sorry if this is a very n00b question but I don't know much about js... would you mind editing the jsfiddle so I can see how that works? thanks!

Comment: I've added a alt attribute to the images on this fiddle. The caption is loaded from this alt attribute. So if you want to add more images and provide a caption, just add a `alt` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/fswe4azh/3/